# Is it possible to perform database operation on locally stored DB through javascript (WebSQL or Indexeddb)

Tags: javascript, android, indexeddb, web-sql

i am developing offline web app for android platform and i want to use offline database for it. Is there any way to connect to locally stored database through javascript. like

```
    var db = opendatabase("file:///android_asset/myLocalDb.db");
    var Records = db.executeSQL("Select * form myTable");
    echo Records;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/).  It is a NoSQL type database backend, but has great cross platform support so you don't have to worry about the underlying storage mechanism across browsers.  If you have flexibility on the database type, it may be the easiest solution.

Are you making a Cordova app, or in-browser hybrid offline but specifically targeting Android?  You can use SQL Lite with Cordova and bubble up from your Javascript to access the db.  Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609184/1011603

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to package your application and data file as web app by packaging [appcache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). Since browser manage data storage for database (indexeddb or websql), it is not possible to specify them by your file name.